# regular expression to capture groups in selected lines

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have multi line string below (in python) and looking for regex to extract *src, dst and severity*. So in the example below group1 be '10.4.180.5' , group 2 '34.23.21.10' and group 3 'critical'

```
    src: 10.4.180.25
    dst: 34.23.21.10
    natsrc: 20.160.129.5
    natdst: 34.33.21.10
... more lines
    severity: critical
... more lines
```

If I try regex like **/src: (\b\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\b)\ndst: (\b\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\b)\n/** with gm flags it will find me *src and dst but not severity* which is few lines down (lines omitted for clarity). Is there a way to do it without including all of these lines between src, dst and severity ?

Comment: Use [`src:\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\ndst:\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\b(?:\n(?!severity).+)*?\nseverity:\s*(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/eudtII/1). Or [this shortened but less efficient](https://regex101.com/r/eudtII/2) variation.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how Python handles RegEx but is there a reason why you can't simply use `^(src|dst|severity): (.*)$` and handle all the matches separately? (The "key", ie. src/dst/severity would be Group 1 and the value would be Group 2.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed need to actually match any number of lines that do not start with `severity` after what your pattern matches. Besides, you may shorten the pattern by using `{3}` limiting quantifier in order not to repeat `\.\d{1,3}` so many times. Note than between a whitespace and a digit, the word boundary is implicit, it is already there, no need to use `\b`.

Use

```
src:\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\ndst:\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?:\n(?!severity).+)*?\nseverity:\s*(.+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eudtII/3)

**Details**

- `src:` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})` - Group 1: IP-like pattern
- `\n` - a newline
- `dst:\s*` - `dst:` with 0+ whitespaces after it
- `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})` - Group 1: IP-like pattern
- `(?:\n(?!severity).+)*?` - 0+ sequences (as few as possible) of

  - `\n(?!severity)` - a newline not followed with `severity`
  - `.+` - the whole line
- `\nseverity:\s*` - a newline, `severity:` substring and 0+ whitespaces
- `(.+)` - Group 3: 1 or more chars up to the end of the line

Note you do not need any DOTALL modifier with this regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `greedy` lookup (think this is the right terminology) `regex` to do this:

```
src: (\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})\ndst: (\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})[\s\S]*?severity: (.+)?\n
```

***I have updated the `regex` so it actually works now!***

so it `searches` for the same bit you have, but then as there are many `lines` between the `dst:` line and the `severity` line, we need to skip all these lines.

To match any number of lines up to the line beginning with `severity:`, we need to match any `characters` - *including new-lines*. To do this, we can use a set of characters: `[\s\S]`. This means match any character which is not a space or is a space, i.e. all characters. We then put this in a `greedy` lookup to match as many *any characters* needed to get to the `severity:` line - so this bit is `[\s\S]*?severity:`.

Now we are at the `severity:` line, we want to `match` and `return` the characters up to the end of that line (up to the new-line `\n` character).  This is done with the similar: `(.+)?\n` syntax but with a `plus` as we want to match *one or more* characters. Also, as want to return this bit, we need to put it in parentheses.

Comment: Joe, this does not not work for me , no match... Wiktor's is working fine

Comment: @irom I forgot something that's why! The dot (`.`) doesn't match a new-line which is why it is failing... I will update the answer

Comment: The dots must be escaped to match literal dots. You may shorten the pattern using limiting quantifiers. `\b` between a space or newline and digit is implicit, the word boundaries are redundant. `[\s\S]*?` is inefficient when parsing long strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree, `\b` is unnecessary so I will remove them now, I had just copied that part from the OP's question . As for the `[/s/S]*?`, that is simply the way I thought of doing it so suggested that way as a solution, I'm not that knowledgeable on `regex`s as a whole and so this way seemed simpler than your negative look ahead for me...

Comment: @JoeIddon You are the second person today who speaks about "simpler". But with regex, "simpler" is not always the right way, especially when the strings you parse are long, of unknown length. Pattern in these cases should be written with the [unroll-the-loop principle](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) in mind.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, your way is definitely the "right" way, nevertheless, for me mine makes more sense as I haven't looked into negative look ahead yet...But your answer is certainly useful so +1 **:)**